# How to use streams to reduce the use of multiple for loops

Tags: java, string, filter, stream

Already existing map and want to filter it and add it to another map.I've done it using for loops but I'm trying to find a more efficient way to do it with streams and filters.

```
Existing map with info already in it:

Map <String,String> infos = new Map<>();


for (String i : infos.keySet()){
   Set<Integer> sets = new Set<>();
   sets.add(Integer.parseInt(i));
}

for (Integer i:sets){
   Map <Integer,String> matches = new Map<>()
   matches.put(i,infos.get(i.toString());
}
```

Comment: What do these loops actually do?  Can you specify the desired outcome please?

Comment: I think: `Set<Integer> sets = new Set<>();` should be outside your first for-loop.

Comment: Define 'efficient'. If you mean: More performant, then streams cannot do that for you. If you mean 'less lines of code', it's java - just.. stop hitting enter. If you mean 'fewer AST nodes' - streams probably also can't do that for you. Perhaps clarify what you mean by 'more efficient'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
    Map<String, String> infos = new HashMap<>();

    Map<Integer, String> result = infos.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    k -> Integer.parseInt(k.getKey()), 
                    Map.Entry::getValue));
```